# passing class object into list

Tags: c#, list

I created a class with passenger properties to get details from user

```
string trainno;
string trainname;
string pname;
string from;
string to;
```

then I created methods to get details

```
public void getDetails()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Trainno ");
    trainno = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Train name ");
    trainname = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the passenger name ");
    pname = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("From : ");
    from = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("To: ");
    to = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and main function

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Class1 tr = new Class1();
    storeDetails sd = new storeDetails();
    tr.getDetails();
    sd.store(tr);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and another class for list

```
class storeDetails
{
    List<Class1> details = new List<Class1> { };
    public void store(Class1 c)
    {
        details.Add(c);
    }
}
```

and I want to store details of more than one user. one user details is the one element in list.

Comment: And where is the question?

Comment: For the record, `Class1` is a horrible class name.

Comment: @Guy Also is `storeDetails`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
Class1 tr;
Console.WriteLine("Enter number users:");
int nbUsers = Console.ReadLine();
List<Class1> sd = new List<Class1>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < nbUsers ; i++)
{
    tr = new Class1();        
    tr.getDetails();
    sd.Add(tr);
}
Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: As with @thierryV 's answer, you need `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` to convert from `string` to `int`. Or just include a "Do you want to add another user?" check in the loop, to save on number parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the users into a list, create a loop and push to it

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number users:");
    int nbUsers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    storeDetails sd = new storeDetails();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < nbUsers ; i++)
    {
        Class1 tr = new Class1();        
        tr.getDetails();
        sd.store(tr);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: `var nbUsers = Console.ReadLine()` implicitly types to `string`, so `i < nbUsers` is a compile error. Did you mean `int nbUsers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`?